# << won't work if adding duplicate item

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, collections, has-many

`Ticket has_many :products` and `Product belongs_to :ticket`
This code:

```
def prepare
  @ticket = Ticket.last
  if @ticket.status != "open"
    @ticket = Ticket.create!
  end
  @ticket.products<<(Product.find(params[:id]))
  respond_to :js
end
```

will not add a new product to @ticket.products, if any instance of the same Product (with the same id) already exists in the @ticket. I want to be able to add two identical products to one ticket - a customer should be able to order two identical beers, shouldn't it?

I digged [here in edgeguides](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-and-belongs-to-many-association-reference), but seems as if only avoiding duplication was covered, not enabling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds more like a many-to-many relationship, which can be managed by a has_many :through association:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Consider a shopping cart example, where a customer can order more than one of the same product through a line item, which has a quantity.

Answer (score 0):

You can just try to add not-yet added products, using [arel](/questions/tagged/arel) gem:

```
@ticket.products << Product.where(Product.arel_table[:id].eq(params[:id])
                           .and(Product.arel_table[:ticket_id].not_eq(@ticket.id)))
```

or for [ruby-on-rails-4](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails-4) you can use `where.not` negation:

```
@ticket.products << Product.where(id: params[:id]).where.not(ticket_id: @ticket.id)
```

Comment: I have doubts if I made it clear: I want to add to one ticket (let's say ticket_id: 1), the same product a few times (let's say product_id: 9). In my understanding, I want to add an already added product for the nth time. So, e.g. `ticket.product_ids` should be able to return something like `[9, 9, 9, other_ids...]`. The problem is I cannot add the same product to the same ticket more than once. I have the impression that you're advising precisely the opposite, i.e. how to not duplicate. Am I wrong?  (Application of your proposed `where.not` does exactly the same what my code does now.)

Comment: @user3010879 it seems m f you wish to allow multiple instantiating the id into the array, just move to manual control, and disable `Ticket has_many :products` and `Product belongs_to :ticket`